# How to allow a combobox to be left blank//skipped on a form

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access, combobox, isnull

I am relatively new to Access and any SQL and VBA I have picked up is self-taught, so I would really appreciate answers that are not too heavily laden with technical terms...that said, I am having an issue with allowing comboboxes to be left blank on a form if the user chooses not to input data.  Also, I am using Access 2016.

Initially the problem I ran into was that if a combobox was entirely skipped and left blank, or if the user selects the combobox and then tries to move on without making a selection from the list, they got the error "You tried to assign the Null value to a variable that is not a Variant data type," and were unable to move on to any other fields on the form or to save the record being entered.

I found this [article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd671280(v=office.12).aspx) that details a possible solution, but I can't seem to get it to work. I made an unbound combobox, set the Row Source to:

```
SELECT EmailID, PersonalEmail FROM EmailT  UNION SELECT "<N/A>","<N/A>" FROM EmailT
ORDER BY PersonalEmail;
```

where PersonalEmail is a field of type short text and the EmailID is an autonumber.  I also followed the article's steps for formatting the combobox (column width, etc.) and set it to Limit to List = Yes.

Here is my exact code:

```
Private Sub Combo62_AfterUpdate()
If Combo62 = "<N/A>" Then
    EmailID = Null
Else
    EmailID = Combo62
End If
End Sub

Private Sub Form_Current()
If IsNull(EmailID) Then
    Combo62 = "<N/A>"
Else
    Combo62 = EmailID
End If
End Sub
```

< N/A> now shows up on my list, but if it is selected I get the error: "The value you entered isn't valid for this field. For example, you may have entered text in a numeric field or a number that is larger than the FieldSize setting permits."

Access's debugger highlights the line:

```
EmailID = Null
```

but I am not sure what steps I should take now to try and fix this.

I am completely open to other methods of allowing the combobox to be left blank if someone knows of a better way to do this also.  For all I know, I am missing something really obvious! Thanks in advance for any insight!

EDIT: Thanks for your help guys, I never did figure out what exactly the problem was, but I got some advice from another forum to rethink my database design so this ended up being a null issue--it's all totally different now!

Comment: Is EmailID a Integer ? Integers can't be null in vba, you will Need to find another way for handling that, for example Setting it to -1

Comment: EmailID is an integer--I didn't realize they couldn't be null.  I tried setting it to -1 but still couldn't get the code to run without the error

Comment: only variants can be null in vba, for numeric datatypes there is a Default constructor with a value (integer is 0). So also your IsNull(EmailID) is useless too

Comment: I tried setting its value to 0, and changing that other line to
If (EmailID = 0) Then
instead of using IsNull, but still no luck.  The same error pops up.

Comment: post your variable definitions or better your full code block. I don't think we will be able to solve it with only this code ;)

Answer (score 0):

If the recordsource for your form contains a query with one-to-many relationships this error may come up.  Try to use only the base table as the recordsource for the form.  Use subforms if you need to display related data.  The rest of the code may then be unnecessary.

Comment: I tried building a new form based on this design method, but ran into problems with that as well. If I try to select an option in the drop down, or try to type in the combobox within the subform first, I get the error "You can't assign a value to this object. *The object may be a control on a read-only form. *The object may be on a form that is open in Design view. *The value may be too large for this field."  I know for sure that it isn't open in design view...